# Debugging ncurses with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, debugging, terminal, eclipse-cdt, ncurses

I'm writing a C++ application using ncurses in Eclipse CDT however I can't run/debug my app in eclipse because the console in eclipse does not work with curses. My app runs fine if I run it from a terminal but I just added some new code and now I'm getting a segmentation fault so I'd like to use the debugger in eclipse to help me fix the issue. Is there a way to have eclipse run/debug my application but use a different terminal for the output much like when you do "tty /dev/pts/1" in gdb? Or any other way to debug a ncures application in eclipse?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 6):

also you should add `TERM=xterm` to Environment in the Debug Configurations dialog

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer.  I've been looking for this answer for a while now.  This is the only thing that worked.  The IDE's terminal emulation won't work with ncurses without the environment variable TERM=xterm.  Not only ncurses+Eclipse CDT, but also ncurses+Code::Blocks and a plethora of other IDEs that encapsulate the terminal have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had debugging problems too when running a program using pdcurses for windows and mingw.
The above solution with TERM = xterm didn't work for me, it might be needed, but I had to set eclipse to use an external console ("...for inferior")

```
Project -> Debug Configurations -> C/C++ Application -> [application name]
Tab: Debugger -> Main
```

the bottom most checkbox "Use external console for inferior (open a new console window for input/output)"

Since I didn't change the above solution (TERM=xterm), that too might be needed.