# Debug ncurses app in Eclipse

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, ncurses

I'm trying to debug an ncurses application in Eclipse CDT. I've managed to get the console output redirected to a real terminal using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938291/debugging-ncurses-with-eclipse-cdt).

However the refresh rate on the terminal seems broken - it constantly spams the text, and doesn't seem to respond to input (difficult to tell with the flickering).

I think this is an Eclipse configuration problem rather than a gdb problem, because if I debug it manually as described [here](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/07-Debugging_Ncurses_Programs.php) this doesn't happen, and if I attempt to debug it 'normally' in Eclipse, the console output scrolls rapidly in much the same way.

I have the terminal set to `sleep 100000000` to avoid Bash fighting for the console input, so I don't think it's that either.

Has anyone managed to do this successfully?