# Debugging ncurses application in Eclipse IDE (Linux)

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, ncurses

I'm creating an ncurses application in the Eclipse IDE (for C/C++ developers), running on Linux Mint. I'm able to successfully launch the application in the gnome terminal from Eclipse, via an external tool configuration, as per the following post:

http://damienlearnsperl.blogspot.com/2015/03/experimenting-with-ncurses-on-linux-in.html

However, so far I've been unable to run the Eclipse debugger alongside the gnome terminal. Running the debugger within Eclipse doesn't work either, since I only see the "Error opening terminal: unknown." message, after which the application is terminated.

I've tried several suggestions found on google, but none of them seem to work, or they're related to outdated/other versions of Eclipse:

[Debugging ncurses with Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938291/debugging-ncurses-with-eclipse-cdt)

https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#HOWTO_debug_applications_which_require_a_real_terminal

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/44886/

The "Attach to Application" option doesn't seem to work either, I'm only seeing "failure to attach to process" errors when trying to attach the debugger to a running gnome terminal.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Ksawery

Comment: Did you compile your application in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, compiled in debug mode.